# Handling numbers larger than Long in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, largenumber

I am Currently trying to write some code in VBA to solve a problem from Project Euler.   I have been trying to answer a question that requires you to find primes that can be divided into a number that will not fit in a long.  Any suggestions as how to handle this problem?

I know I can split the number between two variables and I have done that for addition and subtraction but never division.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basically you're supposed to store the numbers as text and create functions for basic math operations as adding, subtracting, etc. For more information and implementation, take a look here: [Large Number Arithmetic](http://tushar-mehta.com/misc_tutorials/project_euler/LargeNumberArithmetic.htm)

Comment: primes that are divisible by a number...?

Comment: I think we know what he meant @Agent389 primes are not divisible by any number but 1 and itself.  You can actually test this by looping up until square root of a number.  You can probably be even faster then that, I know you shouldn't have to go to half of that number (division, so the square root is a bit faster).

Comment: Sorry for the misswording, I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7):

You can define a Decimal data type (12 Bytes),
but only within a variant.

`Dim i As Variant`

`i = CDec(i)`

Answer (score -6):

Use the "Double" data type that takes larger values.

Comment: Using a "Double" is a bad idea as it's limited to a set number of significant figures so you'll lose accuracy with larger numbers.