# VB 6 -Overflow exception - runtime error using Val() function

Tags: vb6

I am getting runtime overflow exception when using below code:

My application is in visual basic 6.0.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim strItn As String
strItn = "1d998" 'when strItn has '1d998' then only error comes

If Val(strItn) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("test1")
Else
    MsgBox ("else")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scientific notation, `1d998` is `1 * 10^998`, which is ten to the power 998.

That number is bigger than [can be stored](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx) in a variable of any type available in VBA.

If you actually want to perform large number arithmetic with this number, it might be worth checking out [Handling numbers larger than Long in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1840661/11683).

Comment: Thanks @GSerg. Any way to get numeric value from this string value using Val()?

Comment: Numeric value of this string has 998 zeros. What are you going to do with it and where are you going to store it?

Comment: My worry was - how do i avoid to get such kind of error - when value of strINT could be any string value? @GSerg - any suggestion?

Comment: You either pass it to `Val` and handle the exception, or check first with `IsNumeric`. `IsNumeric("1d998")` is `False`. E.g. `IsNumeric("1d308")` is `True`.

Comment: There are some other values like '1b998' doesn't throw any error. @GSerg.How do i get the list of scientific values like '1d998' ? any idea?

Comment: Also - I was expecting Val("1d998") = 1 as return value. Since Val() will return numeric value from string value. if we use Val("123A124") will return 123 @GSerg.

Comment: `1b998` does not throw because it's not a number in scientific notation, at which point Val stops at first non-numeric symbol [as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx), and the value will be `1`. There is no list of scientific values because such list would be infinitely large. [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is a set of rules, not a complete list of numbers.

Comment: ok @GSerg. I would wanted to check - just that it should not be 0 return value when using val("1d998"). This mean value should be >0

Comment: Now we have finally arrived to the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you were having. And the answer is, I have no idea, because only you know what kind of inputs you get and what part of them is considered a valid number. There is unlimited number of ways in which you can transform your data before passing it to `Val`, and only you know which ones will not break whatever logic you have behind this. It might be that you simply want to truncate the input at the first non-digit.

Comment: I'm not at my home computer, so I can't verify, and I may be confusing this with Java - my current langua franca, but I believe you can say: If strNum IsNumeric Then... or maybe it's If IsNumeric(strNum) Then... or I could be mis-remembering, or it could be alternate coding facts :)

Comment: @BillHileman No, that's correct, but it [has been mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260764/vb-6-overflow-exception-runtime-error-using-val-function/43260900?noredirect=1#comment73591223_43260900) and found [not good enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260764/vb-6-overflow-exception-runtime-error-using-val-function/43260900?noredirect=1#comment73591593_43260900) :)

Comment: I see the point, thanks.  It would indeed pass true in his example, then fail again.  I would suggest creating a function to return true if a string contains any non-numeric character.  I haven't played with the like statement much, but perhaps that might be a quick way to check?  An implied If could be used if it could be made a one-liner <warning dream code ahead> Iff(strNum Like "#", "All Numeric","Contains non-numerics")

Comment: Actually my example doesn't "return true if..." but you get the point

Answer (score 1):

Just use an "enhanced" `Val` function like this

```
Public Function C_Val(ByVal Value As String) As Double
    C_Val = Val(Replace(Replace(Value, "e", "_"), "d", "_"))
End Function
```

On `1d987` input should return `1` w/o overflowing. Note that `e` is in scientific notation too, and `Val` can overflow on.